# Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on boolean | Line 20

Tags: php, html

So like mentioned in the title it gives me the error: 'Fatal Error: Call to a member function count() on boolean | Line 20'

What I'm trying to do is when the user pressed the register button it will then refer to this file to do some validation to see if it exists, valid, etc.

Here is the source code of the trouble file.

user.php

```
    <?php
    class User {
    private $_db, $_data;

    public function __construct($user = null) {
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
    }

    public function create($fields = array()){
        if(!$this->_db->insert('users', $fields)) {
            throw   new Exception('There was a problem creating user');
        }
    }

    public function find($user = null) {
        if($user) {
            $fields = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
            $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($fields, '=', $user));

            if($data->count()) {
                $this->_data = $data->first();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function login($username = null, $password = null) {
        $user = $this->find($username);
        print_r($_data);
        return false;
    }
    }
```

index.php

```
    <?php 
    include_once('core/init.php'); 

    if(Input::exists()) {
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {
        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'email' => array('required' => true),
            'password' => array('required' => true)
        ));

        if($validation->passed()) {
            $user = new User();
            $login = $user->login(Input::get('email'), Input::get('password'));

            if($login) {
                echo 'Success';
            } else {
                echo '<p>Sorry, incorrect credentials</p>';
            }
        } else {
            foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
                echo $error, '</br>';
            }
        }
    }
    }
    ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html>

   <html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <link rel='shortcut icon' href='favicon.ico'/>

        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='res/css/bootstrap.css'/>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='res/css/jquery-ui.css'/>

        <script type='text/javascript' src='res/js/jquery-ui.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='res/js/bootstrap.js'></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav id='navContainer'>
            <div id='hIconWrapper'><img id='headerIcon' src='res/icon.png'></img></div>
        </nav>
        <div id='loginContainer'>
        <div id='header'><span>Login</span></div>
        <div id='inputContainer'>
            <form method='post' action=''>
                <label id='labelFormEmail'>Email</label></br><input type='email' name='email' placeholder='Email'/></br></br>
                <label id='labelFormPassword'>Password</label></br><input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password'/></br>
                <a href='forgot.php' class='forgot'>Forgot ?</a>
                <input type='hidden' name='token' value='<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>'/>
                <button class='btn btn-default btn-primary' id='myBtn' type='submit' name='submit'>Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

File List:

- DB.php [HERE](http://pastebin.com/Zib4RMXf)

What I've tried:

- I already have done a mass search using google by typing in the error but I keep getting the count on non-object thing. Dunno if that's the same thing but I've tried using one of them and it partially works.
- Checked the video that I'm following which is 'PHP OOP Login/Register System 16/23'. Don't know if I'm just not seeing it but if it is please point it out. :)

If you guys need to see other code files please feel free to tell me so I can add it here.

Comment: what are you doing and what do you want to achieve and what is your real question.

Comment: It means that `$data = $this->_db->get('users', array($fields, '=', $user));` is returning a Boolean, not a recordset.... so what does the get method look like

Comment: And your `print_r($_data);` in `login()` won't help: `$data` doesn't exist in the login() method.... perhaps you meant `print_r($this->_data);`

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for the explanation there. I will dig deeper into it and see if I can come up with my own solution. Also what do you mean by 'what does the get method look like'. Do you want to see a specific file? I'm a beginner sorry if I don't understand.

Comment: The `get()` method is part of the `DB` class, so it will be in whatever file the DB class is defined in

Comment: @MarkBaker Do you know why it would return a boolean instead of a dataset?

Comment: Not without seing the code I don't; though I'd guess it's returning a boolean false to flag an error of some kind

Comment: @MarkBaker The DB file has been added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72408/discussion-between-repeatercreeper-and-mark-baker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my problem was at Line 18 of the User.php file. It was checking for the username column not EMAIL which was the column that existed within my database. So basically all I had to do was change the ternary operator to:

```
$field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'email';
```

Did some testing and it works! So thanks to everyone who tried to help me out as best as they could especially to Mark Baker for pointing out this code:

```
$data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));
```

User.php

```
<?php
class User {
private $_db, 
             $_data;

public function __construct($user = null) {
    $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
}

public function create($fields = array()){
    if(!$this->_db->insert('users', $fields)) {
        throw   new Exception('There was a problem creating user');
    }
}

public function find($user = null) {
    if($user) {
        $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
        $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));

        if($data->count()) {
            $this->_data = $data->first();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function login($username = null, $password = null) {
    $user = $this->find($username);

    if($user){
        if(Hash::check($password, $this->data()->password)) {
            Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private function data() {
    return $this->_data;
}
}
```